# C# Win Forms issues deleting dynamically created controls

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, controls

I have a function that reads info from a db and dynamically creates checkbox controls when a menu item is selected from a combobox.

When the user selects a different item from the combobox, I am attempting to delete any existing checkboxs already on the page. However, the delete function only deletes every other checkbox. Any idea what im doing wrong?

The form is super basic, just one form, no tabs, only this single combobox and the dynamically created checkboxes.

```
  private void serverModels_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DeleteBoxes();

        List<string> eqpIDs = new List<string>();
        try
        {
            DataExtractor dataExtract = new DataExtractor(DataBase.TCDBServerName, DataBase.TCDBname, DataBase.TCDBUserID, DataBase.TCDBPassword);
            eqpIDs = dataExtract.GetToolsByServerModel(Convert.ToString(serverModels.SelectedItem));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.InsertSystemLog(e.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            return;
        }


        for(int i = 0; i < eqpIDs.Count; i++)
        {
            CheckBox box = new CheckBox();
            box.Checked = true;
            box.Tag = "TOOL";
            box.Text = eqpIDs[i];
            box.AutoSize = true;
            box.Location = new Point(50 + 75 * (i / 17), (i % 17) * 25 + 120);
            this.Controls.Add(box);
        }
    }

    private void DeleteBoxes()
    {
        foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
        {
            if (c is CheckBox && c.Tag.ToString() == "TOOL" )
                c.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dispose is removing the control from the Controls collection as well as disposing of the control.

As noted [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.remove%28v=vs.110%29.aspx),

> When a Control is removed from the control collection, all subsequent controls are moved up one position in the collection.

That is why your logic is skipping every other CheckBox.

Try using a **for** loop in reverse like this:

```
for (int ii = Controls.Count - 1; ii >= 0; ii--)
{
    if (Controls[ii] is CheckBox && Controls[ii].Tag.ToString() == "TOOL")
        Controls[ii].Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be happening because you are modifying your control's `Controls` collection while iterating over it.  Try something like this instead:

```
private void DeleteBoxes()
{
    List<Control> toDispose = new List<Control>();
    foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
    {
        if (c is CheckBox && c.Tag.ToString() == "TOOL" )
            toDispose.Add(c);
    }
    foreach (Control c in toDispose)
    {
        c.Dispose();
    }
}
```